# Name instead of id in mysql+PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, relation

I have this structure in my db, please check here in fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8354/1

I have the problem in the columns pais, departamento and ciudad, in fiddle show me nice the relation but in my page don't...I really tried of many form..but always show me the first option in every table... not like in fiddle that works very well! (in fiddle can't insert all the names and id of every table, but for the example I think is enough)

Can you please give me a solution about this? I have this code in my page:

```
<?
$query = "SELECT P.IDPAIS, lp.opcion,
(SELECT opcion FROM lista_paises WHERE id = IDPAIS)
AS opcion
FROM PACIENTES P
INNER JOIN lista_paises lp
ON  P.IDPAIS = lp.id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$opcion = $row['opcion'];
?>
```

and to show the name in the page of every user this:

```
Departamento : <b> <? echo $opcion1; ?> </b> | Municipio/Ciudad : <b><? echo $opcion2; ?> </b> | Pa&iacute;s : <b> <? echo $opcion; ?></b>
```

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP sample is only going to return one value from your query.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If you want all the results, use a statement like:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
    ... do something with $row
}
```

Comment: this is the code to anybody need something like this:     `<? 
 $query = "SELECT P.IDPAIS, lp.opcion, (SELECT opcion FROM lista_paises WHERE id = IDPAIS) AS opcion FROM PACIENTES P INNER JOIN lista_paises lp ON  P.IDPAIS = lp.id WHERE id_paciente = '$id_paciente'";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );   
 $stmt->execute();
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
 foreach( $rows as $row )
 {
?>
<? echo $row['opcion'] ?>
<?  } ?>`